# Alexandrov's compactification in certain example

Tags: general-topology

I am sure that this problem have appeared couple of times in this forum but I remember I have never seen the detailed proof. I will give quite a detailed proof because I have learnt this topic few days ago and I would like to know am I understand everything correctly.

Show that the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is homeomorphic with the subspace $\{0\}\cup \{1/n : n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Proof:** Let $X=\mathbb{Z}_+$ and being as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ which is Hausdorff it implies that $X$ is itself Hausdorff. Also $X$ is not compact since the open covering $\{\{n\}: n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ have not finite covering. Note that $\{n\}$ is open in $\mathbb{Z}_+$ because it is equal to $(n-1,n+1)\cap \mathbb{Z_+}$. Also $X$ is locally compact since for any point $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ we can write $n\in \{n\}\subseteq \{n\}$ where $\{n\}$ is open and compact.

Then all this implies that there is 1-point compactification of $X$  which we will denote by $Y$, where $Y=X\cup \{\infty\}$ and $Y$ is compact, Hausdorff space.

Let's define the function $f:Y\to K$ where $K=\{0\}\cup \{1/n : n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ by the equation:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}, & \text{if }x \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \\
0, & \text{if }x=\infty
\end{cases}$$

Then it is easy to see that $f$ is surjective and injective $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is bijective.

Since $Y$ is compact  and $K$ is Hausdorff being as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and **if we can show** that $f$ is continuous then it follows that $f$ is homeomorphism (this is a classic result from general topology).

Let's try to show that $f$ is continuous.

Any basis element of $K$ has form $(a,b)\cap K$. The following cases are possible:

1) If $K\cap (a,b)=\varnothing$ then $f^{-1}(\varnothing)=\varnothing$.

So suppose that $K\cap (a,b)\neq \varnothing$.

2) If $0\notin K\cap (a,b)$ then $K=\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=K}^{L}$ and hence $f^{-1}(K)=\{n\}_{n=K}^{L}$ is open in $Y$ since each $\{n\}$ is open in $Y$.

3) If $0\in K\cap (a,b)$ then it also contains all but finitely many $\frac{1}{n}$. So $K=\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\geq N}$ then $f^{-1}(K)=\{\infty\} \cup \{n\}_{n\geq N}$ and the last expression can be written as $Y-\{n\}_{n<N}$ which is open in $Y$ since finite set $\{n\}_{n<N}$ is compact in $Y$.

Hence $f$ is continuous and $f$ is homeomorphism.

**Remark:** I was using that fact that the topology of $Y$ consists of sets of the following two types: $U$ is open in $X$ and $Y-C$ where $C$ is compact subspace of $X$. For the details see the proof of the Theorem 29.1 from Munkres.

I would be very grateful if anyone who knows this topic will take a look at my reasoning.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: $f(n)=1/n$ for $n\in X$ and $f(\infty)=0$ is clearly a bijection from $X'=X\cup \{\infty\}$ to $Y.$ If $V\subset Y$ is open in $Y$ then (i) if $0\not \in V$ then  $\infty \not \in f^{-1}V$ so $f^{-1}V$ is open in $X',$... (ii) if $0 \in V$ then $V$ is co-finite in $Y$... so $\infty \in f^{-1}V$ and $ f^{-1}V$ is co-finite in $X'$... so $f^{-1}V$ is open in $X'$... Therefore $f$ is continuous.